# Android Homescreen Widget ListView ViewHolder Pattern

Tags: android, listview, widget, home-screen-widget

I've got a homescreen widget loading a list of custom views fully up and running.  Data is fed by a custom backend and new items are being properly reflected in the widget's list when I refresh it via a custom widget button.

One thing I noticed is that the homescreen widget is lacking in its support of widgets (views).  One area I noticed was lacking was in respect to ListViews in that I was not able to implement the ViewHolder pattern.  The main issue being that the getViewAt() method only provides the position as a parameter, unlike the regular ListAdapter, which also provides the convertView in its getView() method.  An example of the RemoveViewFactory class is shown below:

```
class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private static final int mCount = 10;
    private List<WidgetItem> mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<WidgetItem>();
    private Context mContext;
    private int mAppWidgetId;

    public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    ...
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {   
        // Construct a remote views item based on the app widget item XML file, 
        // and set the text based on the position.
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_item, mWidgetItems.get(position).text);

        ...
        // Return the remote views object.
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this pattern with homescreen widget and RemoteViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the very simple reason that you do not have any views. The home screen has the views. The point behind a `ViewHolder` is to cache `findViewById()` lookups, and those happen in the home screen's process, not yours.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare!  Do you know if the ListView in Homescreen widgets are optimized to recycle views on its own?  It seems inefficient to create a new RemoteViews object for each position when needed in getViewAt() method for RemoteViewsFactory.  This is very much like inflating a list item and then calling findViewById() each time getView() is called in a ListAdapter.

Comment: @TravisYim: "Do you know if the ListView in Homescreen widgets are optimized to recycle views on its own?" -- I doubt that it does, but I do not know for certain. "It seems inefficient to create a new RemoteViews object for each position when needed in getViewAt() method for RemoteViewsFactory" -- IPC introduces some unavoidable inefficiencies.